# Extracting Application Version/Revision from a .pubxml file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, publish

I want to read fields from a .pubxml file during runtime. I'm working on a code base that uses a .pubxml file called "**Production Publish Profile.pubxml**". I'm unfamiliar with how publishing .NET programs is handled, and the lead developer has recently updated this process.

This file is located under the **Project -> Properties -> PublishProfiles** directory, and is structured roughly like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationRevision>6</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>7.1.0.*</ApplicationVersion>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What I'm looking to do is extract the Application Revision and Version fields during run time, so that I can insert those into necessary error logs. How can I access these fields freely, or at least read them when compiling the program?

Comment: That file is *not* used during runtime. It's only used by Visual Studio to deploy applications but is never deployed itself, just like eg `csproj`

Comment: The `pubxml` file is the publishing profile. It's not deployed itself. Its information is used to generate the information stored in assembly attributes and the application's manifest